# chmod setting the permissions value dynamicly

Tags: php, arrays, file-permissions, chmod

Ok test 1 and 2 work fine, but If I cast the value from an array it doesn't work.

```
$file = '/test/file.xlsx';
echo "Original Permissions: ".substr(decoct(fileperms($file)),2)."<br />\n\r";

// test 1
$permission = 0775;
chmod($file,$permission);
clearstatcache();
echo "Test 1 Permissions: ".substr(decoct(fileperms($file)),2)."<br />\n\r";

// test 2
define("PERMISSION", 0775);
chmod($file,PERMISSION);
clearstatcache();
echo "Test 2 Permissions: ".substr(decoct(fileperms($file)),2)."<br />\n\r";
```

Output:

```
Original Permissions: 1407<br />
Test 1 Permissions: 0775<br />
Test 2 Permissions: 0775<br />
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
// $ini_array['excel_file_info']['excel_file_permission'] 
// is in a ini file with the value set to 0775
if(isset($ini_array['excel_file_info']['excel_file_permission'])) {
    $excel_file_permission  = $ini_array['excel_file_info']['excel_file_permission'];  
    define("EXCEL_FILE_PERMISSION", $excel_file_permission);
} else {
    $excel_file_permission  = 0777; 
    define("EXCEL_FILE_PERMISSION", $excel_file_permission);
}

echo "Permissions Before chmod: ".substr(decoct(fileperms($file)),2)."<br />\n\r";
chmod($file,EXCEL_FILE_PERMISSION);
clearstatcache();
echo "Permissions After chmod: ".substr(decoct(fileperms($file)),2)."<br />\n\r";;
chmod($file,0755);
clearstatcache();
echo "Permissions Hard Coded chmod: ".substr(decoct(fileperms($file)),2)."<br />\n\r";;
```

I get this for file permissions:

```
// Before I chmod
Permissions Before chmod: 0644<br />

// Using the DEFINED CONSTANT w/ set value to 0775
Permissions After chmod: 1363<br />

// Hard Coded 0755
Permissions Hard Coded chmod: 0755<br />
```

EDIT:

```
// test 3
$permission = array('perm' => 0775);
chmod($file,$permission['perm']);
clearstatcache();
echo "Test 3 Permissions: ".substr(decoct(fileperms($file)),2)."<br />\n\r";
```

Test 3 works, but still not the main example. UGH!!!

EDIT #2:

I think I found the problem, when I echo the type of the variable it's a string.

```
echo "Defined Excel File Permission: ".EXCEL_FILE_PERMISSION."\n\r";
echo "Defined Type: ".gettype(EXCEL_FILE_PERMISSION)."\n\r";

Defined Excel File Permission: 0775
Defined Type: string
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think typecasting cause the problem. Try to change:

```
$excel_file_permission  = (int)$ini_array['excel_file_info']['excel_file_permission'];
```

to

```
$excel_file_permission  = intval($ini_array['excel_file_info']['excel_file_permission'], 8);
```

Comment: What is your current value for $ini_array['excel_file_info']['excel_file_permission']? try to put value like '0777' or '0644' or other permission value that you want.

Comment: In the ini I changed the value to 0666, when the script executes I get permission: 1232

Comment: if I wrap the value in single quotes in the ini like this: '0775', I get permissions: 0000

Comment: if I wrap the value in double quotes in the ini like this: "0775", I get permissions: 1407

Comment: if no quotes around the value in the ini like this: 0775, I get permissions: 1407

Comment: Hi Phill, I've updated my answer. Problem solved using intval() function ;)

Comment: Yes, intval() will generate 420 for 0644. But the result is same. Make sure you don't miss second argument for intval() which has value 8.

Comment: I think I missed the ,8 in the intval(). seems to be working, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't work because you convert to an integer value when you do `$excel_file_permission  = (int)$ini_array['excel_file_info']['excel_file_permission'];`. An integer is not the same as an octal value...